# DECIMAL does not provide the expected set size

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

There is an example on this documentation page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16&redirectedfrom=MSDN

It says that 123.45 has a precision of 5 and a scale of 2.

To me, that says that when creating a `DECIMAL`, the first number is the precision, and the second number is the amount of that precision that is dedicated to storing decimal points.

But my testing does not agree with that.  Here are a few examples:

```
SELECT 124.28 / 1039.72 -- 0.119532181
SELECT CAST(124.28 AS float) / CAST(1039.72 AS float) -- 0.119532181741238
SELECT CAST(124.28 AS DECIMAL(38,30)) / CAST(1039.72 AS DECIMAL(38,30)) -- 0.119532
```

I would expect `DECIMAL(38,30))` to have at least as many digits as the `float` example, but it has less.

How do I setup a decimal to give more digits in the result?

Comment: The documentation is totally accurate, what you are asking is about decimal division and the resultant decimal prevision. Nothing to do with the definition of decimal itself.

Comment: In the remarks section it explains what happens when you divide 2 decimal numbers. And I *think* from what I can tell, that the values are so large, that its dropping back to defaults.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/77664/how-does-sql-server-determine-precision-scale

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41743/automatic-decimal-rounding-issue/41745#41745

Comment: You can see what is happening if you stuff the value into a #temp table then query the column definitions e.g. https://dbfiddle.uk/_2k6wEFu

Comment: Just for fun...  I recently learned that NASA calculates Pi to 15 decimals.  They can locate Voyager I which is 15 billion miles away within 6 inches.   Now this made me chuckle because I was guilty of thinking more is better.   https://xkcd.com/2170/

Comment: _I would expect DECIMAL(38,30)) to have at least as many digits as the float example, but it has less._ I wouldn't since `float` is an approximate numeric type - it cannot represent `0.119532181` accurately so it approximates it as `0.119532181741238`.